# as.POSIXlt is producing NA in R

Tags: r, date

I have tried to find a solution for my problem but could not have found any. So in R I am getting NA when I will run a script below:

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXlt("Thu May 28 10:39:58 EEST 2015", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EEST %Y"))
```

I have found that the format may not be correct but I will not understand how I should change it. Could anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: It's probably not very helpful but the output I'm getting from your code above is `[1] 1432827598`. Maybe try and restart your working session in R and see if that helps.

Comment: Would like to add I'm getting that too.

Comment: Well, I have tried to restart my session and computer also but it wont help nothing. Problem is maybe with my settings or something?

Comment: Have you updated R recently?

Comment: I have installed it two months ago and have not updated it after installation. Do you believe that  I should have to?

Comment: I believe that my R does not support the formats where months or weekdays have been wrote (%a, %b and so on). Do anyone have same problem? How do you have solved it?

Comment: Sounds like a difference in OS or locales. The date-time conversions do have an OS dependence. You should post the first few lines of `sessionInfo()`-output.

Comment: R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Finnish_Finland.1252  LC_CTYPE=Finnish_Finland.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Finnish_Finland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=Finnish_Finland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2

Comment: `LC_TIME=Finnish_Finland.1252` So what are the abbreviations for days of the week and months in Finnish?

Comment: Well, it works with the Finnish names, thank you! I changed the value of LC_TIME locale and now it works fine.