# as.POSIXlt returns NA

Tags: r, datetime, locale

Trying to convert `chr` to a proper date format in R, I use the following example, returning an error.

```
> as.POSIXlt(strptime("Tue, 23 Mar 2010 14:36:38 -0400", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"))
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments on [as.POSIXlt is producing NA in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006960/as-posixlt-is-producing-na-in-r) I realized I have the wrong `LC_TIME` set for my session.

```
> Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
[1] "German_Germany.1252"
```

The format above is in English and not in German. So changing the locale should be the solution and voilà!

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
[1] "English_United States.1252"
> as.POSIXlt(strptime("Tue, 23 Mar 2010 14:36:38 -0400", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"))
[1] "2010-03-23 19:36:38"
```

Comment: `strptime` returns a POSIXlt object.  You can drop `as.POSIXlt`